How to maintain the UIView C position same in UIView A?
What I want is to move UIViewB and maintain all the views position like nothing happened.  I want viewC back to the original place before viewB is moved how ? This must apply to all angles regardless how viewB rotate. How can I do that ?
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create UIViewA
        let viewA = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
        viewA.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(viewA)

        // Create UIViewB
        let viewB = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 200, height: 200))
        viewB.backgroundColor = .green
        viewA.addSubview(viewB)

        // Create UIViewC
        let viewC = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        viewC.backgroundColor = .blue
        viewB.addSubview(viewC)

        // Initial position of viewC in viewA's coordinate system
        let initialCPositionInA = viewC.convert(viewC.bounds.origin, to: viewA)
        
        // Rotate viewB by 45 degrees
        viewB.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 4.5) // 45 degrees

        // Calculate the movement delta of viewB
        let movementDelta = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)

        // Move viewB up by -50 pixels
        viewB.center = CGPoint(x: viewB.center.x, y: viewB.center.y + movementDelta.y)
        
        // I want viewC back to the original place before viewB is moved how ? This must apply to all angles regardless how viewB rotate
    }
}

I have tried many different solutions, by moving the y position of the UIViewC but it is returning weird results as there are transform applied to the UIViewB which also applied to UIViewC.

Why did you add the views as subviews of each other if you want them to have independent frames?

Due to some requirements given, I need to do that @Sweeper

Just to be clear - you want the position of view C to stay the same, but not its rotation. Is that correct? You want view C to rotate along with view B?

@Sweeper view C must rotate along with view B, after that view B moved up view C must maintain its original position just now

You should work in the coordinate system of view A (or any coordinate system that is fixed).
Before view B moves, get the centre of view C (as a coordinate in view A). Keep in mind that center is a coordinate in the parent's coordinate system.
let oldCenter = viewB.convert(viewC.center, to: viewA)

Then after moving view B, set the centre of view C back to oldCenter:
viewC.center = viewB.convert(oldCenter, from: viewA)

